# Negative step indexing on List in Python

Tags: python, list, indexing, slice, reversing

So, my confusion on slicing a list in reverse order took a hit when I tried to compare the two commands, one with their default values and the other one with the actual command

PS: I'm trying to reverse a list using slicing

```
List = ["Apple", "Grapes", "Mango", "Papaya"]

# Reversing
print(List[::-1])
```

Here, I get the desired output by skipping both start and end arguments which are optional.

But when I include their default values which are start=0 and end=len(List), I get an empty list

```
print(List[0:3:-1])
```

[Empty list output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06z57.png)

Why so?

Comment: Your confusion took a hit :D so everything is clear now?

Comment: Aww, thanks for the reference links. I'm on it now!

Answer (score 0):

I think the range should be indicated in reverse order: print(List[3:0:-1]) - although I don't get 'Apples' if I do this.

Why not use reversed(List) instead?

Comment: Ikk, I just wanna understand the background on this.